# Do eigenvectors of a matrix and its transpose, for different eigenvalues, annihilate each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, transpose

The typical proof that I have seen goes like this,

Take $x$ to be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $a$, and take $y$ to be an eigenvector of $A^T$ with eigenvalue $b$.  Assume that $a \ne b$.

Then, by definition of the transpose (or adjoint), we have that

$$<Ax, y> = <x, A^Ty>$$
$$\iff<ax, y> = <x, by>$$
$$= a<x,y> = \bar{b}<x,y>$$
$$\implies <x,y> = 0$$
as $a \ne b$.

However, as you see: I've used the fact that the inner product is *conjugate* linear in the second argument, so the above "proof" doesn't seem to work, since $a$ could be equal to $\bar{b}$, and thus $<x,y> = 0$ is not necessarily true.

Where is my mistake in reasoning?

(For instance, the above proof is used in Peter Lax's Linear Algebra book.)

Comment: He is probably talking about the case where the ground field is real. If so, we speak of an eigenpair $(a,x)$ of a linear operator $A$ only when both $a,x$ are real. Since the usual inner product in $\mathbb R^n$ is bilinear, what he says is right. But you are correct if the ground field is complex. In that case we still have $y^\top x=0$, but not necessarily that $\langle x,y\rangle=y^\ast x=0$.

Comment: Ah, right @user1551, that works then - and it also helps in proving one part of Perron's theorem, since the dominant eigenvalue is real.  You said that we would still have $y^T x = 0$:  I am guessing you are applying the Spectral Theorem, but if the ground field were complex, the matrix is required to be normal (and symmetric, if the ground field were real).  Is this what you're saying?  Just want to be sure, since here I have not assumed that $A$ is normal or symmetric. Thanks so much,

Comment: No. We are talking about the relationship between eigenvectors of $A$ and eigenvectors of $A^\top$ (not $A^\ast$). If $Ax=ax$ and $A^\top y=by$, then $by^\top x=(y^\top A)x=y^\top(Ax)=ay^\top x$. So, if $a\ne b$, we must have $y^\top x=0$, regardless of the field. If the field happens to be real and $x,y$ are real, we can of course interpret $y^\top x$ as the Euclidean inner product between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ah, very cool.  I've used this in the past, so it's nice to see the simple one-line proof again.  I'm happy to accept your comments as an answer, if you want to convert them.  Thanks again, @user1551.  Have a great night :)

Answer (score 1):

$A=\pmatrix{i & 0\cr 0&-i}$ in the orthogonal basis  its transpose $\pmatrix{-i & 0\cr 0& i}$ but $e_1$ is not orthogonal to $e_1$.

You use the fact that $\langle A(x),y\rangle=\langle x, A^t(y)\rangle$, this is true for the conjugate transpose not for the transpose. Since $\langle A(e_1),e_1\rangle=i$ and $\langle e_1,A(e_1)\rangle=-i$.

Comment: $e_1$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $A^t$ associated to different eigenvalues.

Comment: if $A$ is the first matrix, what is its transpose ?

Comment: hah, i was thinking you was using the conjugate transpose isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

They only annihilate when $a\ne b.$  So, the assumption $a\ne b$ is fine.

In the example above, if $a=b$ then $<x,y> \ne 0$

Here is annother thought...

$A = PDP^{-1}$

$A^T = {P^{-1}}^TDP^{T}$

The eigenvectors or $A^T$ are the columns of ${P^{-1}}^T$

Or the rows of $P^{-1}$

And when $n\ne m$ the $n^{th}$ row anihilates the $m^{th}$ column.